# clicking on the circle next to iboutlet creates breakpoint instead of showing me storyboard link

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, iboutlet

I have a possible xcode settings issue. Usually clicking on the circle next to a connected `IBOutlet` in code opens up a small menu showing the connected storyboard element. this is shown in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27057437/4677074

But for me it just creates a breakpoint. rightclicking doesnt work either. also the circle is a little smaller then usual. how can i enable the menu again so i can find the connected storyboard element? i am using xcode 7.0.1

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84MpJ.png)

Comment: You have to click on the circle. Anywhere even little bit outside the circle will set the break point.

Comment: add Xcode version and show a screenshot of this circle small than usual :) !

Comment: screenshot added. yea i tried clicking exactly on the circle. doesnt work.

Comment: I have the same probleme on Xcode 7.3.1, no matter where I click, in the very center of the IBOutlet circle, or near it, the only thing I get is to set a breakpoint on this line. Weird... tried to clean / restart / reboot, it's always the same, don't know why... please help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the answer ! To enable / disable the ability to see the connected storyboard element by clicking on the small circle on the left of an IBOutlet property, just open the "Editor" panel menu of Xcode an click on Show / Hide Code coverage !

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: I tried that on Xcode 9.1 and it didn't help. I still have the same problem and can't see the connected storyboard element. Other ideas?