# XCode: Refer from an IBOutlet to Storyboard

Tags: xcode, storyboard

Is there a way to go from an IBOutlet in a ViewController and have it open where it is contained in a Storyboard?

I'm working on a app I didn't build and there's a NSLayoutConstraint as an IBOutlet but when I go to the View in Storyboard where I thought it should be there's no constraint there connected back to the viewcontroller.

I know in Storyboard I can right click on an object and view it's outlet connections, wondering if there's a reverse of that.

Thanks

Comment: I found this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27056812/how-to-find-the-ui-element-connected-to-a-specific-iboutlet

Which should work but the file is a Swift file and though there is a circle next to the IBOutlet, it's not grayed out and I can't right click on it.

Comment: Try just clicking and dragging from the circle next to the outlet. I don't think control-clicking works that way when the connector (circle) is next to code.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out, the view was a stand alone XIB. The person(s) who initially developed this app seem to have hated Storyboards and XIBs and hacked it up as much as possible. :D